# Flashing hex over a serial port to an LPC Microcontroller with Pyserial does not work

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pyserial

I am using Arch Linux and have not found any software that allows me to flash files onto my microcontroller. My school's documentation for flashing had a python file, and when I run it, I get the Error message root: Timed out!.

The code:

```
########
# CHANGELOG:
# 2016-02-15 : Working Skeleton for Flashing a Hex file to SJOne comeplete!
#

import string
import os
import time
import struct
import binascii
import math
import serial.serialutil
import logging
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/')
from intelhex import IntelHex
import serial

###############################################################################
################# CONFIGURATION FOR pyFlash - Hyperload ######################
###############################################################################
sDeviceFile = "/dev/ttyUSB0"   # Device File Path
sDeviceBaud = 38400          # Suitable Device Baud Rate
sHexFilePath = "/SJSU_Dev2/projects/lpc1758_freertos/_build/lpc1758_freertos.hex"
sGenerateBinary = "y" # "y" - Yes | "n" - No
###############################################################################

#### LOGGING OPTIONS ####
PYFLASH_DEBUG_LOG = "no" # "yes" - Debug Version. "no" - Release Version
#########################


if PYFLASH_DEBUG_LOG == "yes":
    PYFLASH_BUILD_LEVEL = "DEBUG"
else:
    PYFLASH_BUILD_LEVEL = "RELEASE"

if PYFLASH_BUILD_LEVEL == "DEBUG":
    logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.DEBUG)
else:
    logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO)


# Things to Do:
# 1. Display Platform Information                               [DONE]
# 2. Enable a Debug/Release Switch                              [DONE]
# 3. Create ~/.pyFlash and store last used options for Flashing [PEND]
# 4. Handle Exceptions                                          [PEND]
# 5. Ensure packing is done based on Endianness                 [PEND]
# 6. Re-write program with classes using this as the backbone.  [PEND]
# 7. Incorporate design decisions keeping the GUI in mind       [PEND]

# Issues Faced
# 1. Handling Bytes were hard - Use bytearray for most of the IO related functions. Difference between bytes and bytearray is that the latter is mutable.
#    Bytes are types that are not mutable. Any changes done on them will cause a new alloc + concat and reassigning.

# Global Defines

ApplicationVersion = "1.0"
ToolName = "pyFLASH - HYPERLOAD"
ToolInfo = "Flashing Tool for SJOne"
BaudList = [4800, 9600, 19200, 38400]
ControlWordList = b'\x80\xf8\xfe\xff'
SpecialChar = {'Dollar' : '$', 'OK' : '!', 'NextLine' : '\n', 'STAR' : '*'}
sCPUSpeed = 48000000
sInitialDeviceBaud = 38400

ByteReference = b'\xff\x55\xaa'

# Common Util Functions
def printIntroMessage():
    print ("#######################")
    print (" ", ToolName)
    print (ToolInfo)
    print ("#######################")
    print ("Version    : ", ApplicationVersion)
    print ("Build Type : ", PYFLASH_BUILD_LEVEL)
    print ("#######################")

    return


def printBytes(mymsg):

    print ("Type info = " + (str)(type(mymsg)))

    if (type(mymsg) == bytes) or (type(mymsg) == bytearray):
        for x in mymsg:
            print ("0x" + '{:x}'.format(x),)

        print ("")
        print ("Total Elements = " + (str)(len(mymsg)))

    elif (type(mymsg) == str):
        printBytes(bytearray(mymsg))

    elif type(mymsg) == int:

        print ("0x" + '{:x}'.format(mymsg),)

    else:
        print (mymsg)

    return

def getBoardParameters(descString):
    boardParametersDict = {'Board' : '', 'BlockSize' : '', 'BootloaderSize' : '', 'FlashSize' : ''}

    # Parsing String to obtain required Board Parameters
    boardParametersList = descString.split(':')

    boardParametersDict['Board'] = boardParametersList[0]
    boardParametersDict['BlockSize'] = boardParametersList[1]
    boardParametersDict['BootloaderSize'] = (int(boardParametersList[2]) * 2)
    boardParametersDict['FlashSize'] = boardParametersList[3]

    print ("\n***** Board Information ********")
    print ("Board              = " + (str)(boardParametersDict['Board']))
    print ("Block (Chunk) Size = " + (str)(boardParametersDict['BlockSize']) + " bytes")
    print ("Bootloader Size    = " + (str)(boardParametersDict['BootloaderSize']) + " bytes")
    print ("Flash Size         = " + (str)(boardParametersDict['FlashSize']) + " KBytes")
    print ("*********************************\n")

    return boardParametersDict

def printContent(lContent):

    logging.debug("--------------------")
    count = 0;
    totalCount = 0;
    for x in lContent:
        print ('{:2x}'.format(x),)
        if count >= 10:
            print ("\n")
            count = 0
        else:
            count = count + 1
        totalCount = totalCount + 1

    logging.debug("\n--------------------")
    logging.debug("Total Count = ", totalCount)
    logging.debug("--------------------")

    return

def getControlWord(baudRate, cpuSpeed):
    # TODO : Currently using known values. Replace with actual formula
    logging.debug("Retrieving Control Word")

    controlWord = ((cpuSpeed / (baudRate * 16)) - 1)

    return controlWord

def getPageContent(bArray, blkCount, pageSize):

    startOffset = blkCount * pageSize
    endOffset = (startOffset + pageSize - 1)

    #print "Page Start = ", startOffset, " | Page End = ", str(endOffset)

    lPageContent = bytearray(pageSize)
    for x in range(0, pageSize):
        lPageContent[x] = bArray[x + (blkCount * pageSize)]

    #print "Length of x = ", x

    if x != pageSize - 1:
        raw_input()

    return lPageContent


def getChecksum(blocks):

    # Try older method - Add and Pack into integer.
    lChecksum = bytearray(1);
    for x in blocks:
        lChecksum[0] = (lChecksum[0] + x) % 256

    return lChecksum[0]

# Class

### Main Program ###

printIntroMessage()

print (str('-' * (len(sHexFilePath) + 20)))
print ("Hex File Path = \"" + sHexFilePath + "\"")
print (str('-' * (len(sHexFilePath) + 20)))

# Fetching Hex File and Storing
hexFile = IntelHex(sHexFilePath)

if sGenerateBinary == "y":
    # Create a Binary File of this Hex File
    sBinFilePath= sHexFilePath.replace(".hex", ".bin")
    logging.debug("Binary File Path : %s", sBinFilePath)
    hexFile.tofile(sBinFilePath, format='bin')

# Obtain the actual Binary content from the Hex File
binArray = hexFile.tobinarray()

sPort = serial.Serial(
            port = sDeviceFile,
            baudrate = sInitialDeviceBaud,
            parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
            stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
            bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS)

sPort.reset_input_buffer()
sPort.reset_output_buffer()
sPort.flush()

# Setting Initial State of RTS Bit to False
sPort.rts = False;

# Reseting the board by toggling DTR
sPort.dtr = False;

# Reading a Byte from SJOne
msg = sPort.read(1)

if msg is ByteReference[1]:

    sPort.write(ByteReference[1])

    logging.debug("Initial Handshake Initiated! - Received ")

    msg = sPort.read(1)

    if msg is ByteReference[2]:
        logging.debug("Received " + (str)(repr(msg)) + ", Sending Control Word..")

        lControlWordInteger = getControlWord(sDeviceBaud, sCPUSpeed)
        lControlWordPacked = struct.pack('<i', lControlWordInteger)

        msg = sPort.write(bytearray(lControlWordPacked))

        if msg != 4:
            logging.error("Error - Sending control word failed")
        else:
            logging.debug("Sending Control Word Successful!")

            msg = sPort.read(1)

            if msg != lControlWordPacked[0]:
                logging.error("Error - Failed to receive Control Word Ack")
            else:
                logging.debug("Ack from SJOne received!")

                if sDeviceBaud != sInitialDeviceBaud:
                    # Switch to new BaudRate here.
                    logging.debug("Requested Baudrate different from Default. Changing Baudrate..")

                    sPort.baudrate = sDeviceBaud

                else:
                    logging.debug("BaudRate same as Default")

                # Read the CPU Desc String
                msg = sPort.read(1)

                if msg != SpecialChar['Dollar']:
                    logging.error("Failed to read CPU Description String")
                else:
                    logging.debug("Reading CPU Desc String..")

                    CPUDescString = SpecialChar['Dollar']
                    while True:
                        msg = sPort.read(1)

                        if msg == SpecialChar['NextLine']:
                            break

                        CPUDescString = CPUDescString + msg

                    logging.debug("CPU Description String = %s", CPUDescString)

                    boardParameters = getBoardParameters(CPUDescString)

                    # Receive OK from SJOne
                    msg = sPort.read(1)

                    if msg != SpecialChar['OK']:
                        logging.error("Error - Failed to Receive OK")
                    else:
                        logging.debug("OK Received! Sending Block")

                    # Send Dummy Blocks -
                    # Update : We can send the actual blocks itself.


                    # Sending Blocks of Binary File
                    totalBlocks = (len(binArray) * 1.0 / int(boardParameters['BlockSize']))
                    logging.debug("Total Blocks = %f", totalBlocks)

                    paddingCount = len(binArray) - ((len(binArray)) % int(boardParameters['BlockSize']))
                    logging.debug("Total Padding Count = %d", paddingCount)

                    totalBlocks = math.ceil(totalBlocks)    
                    print ("Total # of Blocks to be Flashed = ", totalBlocks)

                    # Pad 0's to binArray if required.
                    binArray = bytearray(binArray)
                    binArray += (b'\x00' * paddingCount)

                    blockCount = 0
                    sendDummy = False
                    #sendDummy = True
                    blockContent = bytearray(int(boardParameters['BlockSize']))

                    if sendDummy == True:
                        logging.debug("FLASHING EMPTY BLOCKS")
#
                    while blockCount < totalBlocks:
                        print ("--------------------")

                        blockCountPacked = struct.pack('<H', blockCount)

                        msg = sPort.write(blockCountPacked[1])
                        if msg != 1:
                            logging.error("Error in Sending BlockCountLowAddr")

                        msg = sPort.write(blockCountPacked[0])
                        if msg != 1:
                            logging.error("Error in Sending BlockCountHiAddr")

                        logging.debug("BlockCounts = %d", blockCount)

                        if sendDummy == False:
                            blockContent = getPageContent(binArray, blockCount, int(boardParameters['BlockSize']))

                        msg = sPort.write(blockContent)
                        if msg != len(blockContent):
                            logging.error("Error - Failed to sending Data Block Content")
                            break

                        #printContent(blockContent)

                        checksum = bytearray(1)

                        checksum[0] = getChecksum(blockContent)

                        logging.debug("Checksum = %d[0x%x]", checksum[0], checksum[0])

                        msg = sPort.write(checksum)
                        logging.debug("Size of Block Written = %d", msg)

                        if msg != 1:
                            logging.error("Error - Failed to send Entire Data Block")

                        msg = sPort.read(1)
                        if msg != SpecialChar['OK']:
                            logging.error("Failed to Receive Ack.. Retrying #" + str(blockCount))
                        else:
                            print ("Block # " + str(blockCount) + " flashed!")
                            blockCount = blockCount + 1

                        print ("--------------------")

                    if blockCount != totalBlocks:
                        logging.error("Error - All Blocks not Flashed")
                        logging.error("Total = " + str(totalBlocks))
                        logging.error("# of Blocks Flashed = " + str(blockCount))
                    else:
                        print ("Flashing Successful!")
                        endTxPacked = bytearray(2)
                        endTxPacked[0] = 0xFF
                        endTxPacked[1] = 0xFF

                        msg = sPort.write(bytearray(endTxPacked))

                        if msg != 2:
                            logging.error("Error in Sending End Of Transaction Signal")

                        msg = sPort.read(1)
                        logging.debug("Received Ack = " + str(msg))

                        if msg != SpecialChar['STAR']:
                            logging.error("Error - Final Ack Not Received")

else :
    logging.error("Timed Out!")

sPort.baudrate = sInitialDeviceBaud


sPort.close()
```

The top half established the correct port (/dev/ttyUSB0) and turns the hex into binary, and the bottom half doing the flashing, which is the aspect that does not work.

The port (/dev/ttyUSB0) and baudrates are correct.

Answer (score 1):

The timeout occurs because the program does not read an expected byte from the device:

```
# Reading a Byte from SJOne
msg = sPort.read(1)

if msg is ByteReference[1]:
   # Programming code
   # ...
else :
    logging.error("Timed Out!")
```

You should probably use [minicom](https://linux.die.net/man/1/minicom) to verify that you can communicate with the device. If you can communicate with minicom, try printing `msg` in the `else` clause.

In the comments, you say that printing `msg` yields

```
b'\x00'
```

However, `ByteReference` is defined as

```
ByteReference = b'\xff\x55\xaa'
```

This means that `ByteReference[1]` should be

```
b'\x55'
```

So `msg` does not match the expected value. This means the `if` clause that performs the programming will not be reached.

Comment: Through CuteCom I can communicate with the device (strangely minicom says it is offline). The device uses an LPC1758 chip, and the drivers are properly loaded.

Comment: Try printing `msg` in the `else` clause.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. Printing msg yields: b '\x00'

Comment: I updated my answer to describe what will happen if `msg` is `b'\x00'`.